# websocket behind a firewall

Tags: windows-server-2003, routing, windows-server-2008-r2, redirection, sockets

I have a computer with a strong CPU and a lot of memory (strongy) running Windows Server 2008 R2, that is blocked by a firewall from any access from the outside world.

I have a computer with a weak CPU and little memory (weaky) running Windows Server 2003, that has port 80 open to the outside world.

I want to put a Java server on strongy, that will connect with the outside world via websockets. I use socket.io implementation based on Netty: https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio . It listens on strongy:8090. There is also an Apache server on strongy that serves the static content.

Now, I know how to route http requests from weaky to strongy - I just put these two lines in httpd.conf on weaky:

```
ProxyPass        /myapp http://strongy/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://strongy/myapp
```

However, this doesn't help with the socket.io requests...

I don't need secure connection, load balancing or any other fancy stuff - just route the requests back and forth.

Comment: Why don't you use Web Services then?

Comment: I think you might need to use netcat to create a connection between two ports on strongy. for example http connection - use netcat to forward connections from port 80 to port 8090.

Comment: What is a strong or weak computer? Does strong mean secure and weak mean non-secure?

Comment: @DaveRook most probably the names resemble 'assumed security level' based on accessibility from the outside world.

Comment: @DaveRook I use socket.io because I want fast full-duplex communication between the clients and my server. For example, when the client sends a service-request, I want the server to be able to send log messages while the request is processed. This is very easy with socket.io. Strong/weak refers to computational power. The strong computer does all the difficult computations.